# Postgres - connect three tables and use aggregate functions on data in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have three tables:

Posts:

```
  id  |  title
------------------
  1   |  post1
  2   |  post2
  3   |  post3
  4   |  post4
```

Comments:

```
  post_id  |  content
-----------------------
     1     |  asd
     1     |  dsad
     1     |  awtihaw
     2     |  aaaaa
     2     |  bbbbbbbb
     4     |  asdasd
```

Votes:

```
  post_id  |  value
-----------------------
     1     |  1
     2     |  1
     2     |  -1
     3     |  1
     3     |  1
     3     |  1
     3     |  -1
```

## Problem

I need to count how many comments and how many likes each post has.

This is my query:

```
SELECT posts.id, COUNT(comments.post_id) as comments, SUM(votes.value) as votes
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id
LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY posts.id
```

And I in fact get a result, **BUT** in the result it says that

**post** with the id **1** has *3 votes* and *3 comments*

where in fact it only has one vote and three comments.
How do I correctly join three tables so it shows the correct result? I need to be able to do this only in queries and preferably in just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution uses correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT p.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM comments c
        WHERE p.id = c.post_id
       ) as num_comments,
       (SELECT SUM(v.value)
        FROM votes v
        WHERE p.id = v.post_id
       ) as net_votes
FROM posts p
ORDER BY p.id;
```

With indexes on `comments(post_id)`, `votes(post_id, value)`, and `posts(id)`, this may be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate separately in `comments` and `votes` and then join to `posts`:

```
SELECT p.id, c.comments_count, v.votes_sum
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id) comments_count
  FROM comments 
  GROUP BY post_id
) c ON p.id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT post_id, SUM(value) votes_sum
  FROM votes 
  GROUP BY post_id
) v ON p.id = v.post_id
ORDER BY p.id
```

This will return `NULL` for posts that don't have any comments or votes.
If you want `0` instead, use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       COALESCE(c.comments_count, 0) comments_count, 
       COALESCE(v.votes_sum, 0) votes_sum
FROM .....
```

Answer (score -1):

I think JOIN is not a way we should try.

Here when we use JOIN, comments for a post is repeated in result for each votes for the same request.
Similarly Votes are repeated for each comments.

In given example you got correct value for comments only beacuse we have only one row in votes for POST_ID 1.

Instead of JOIN, we have to use INNER query to get proper result.